# R data frames, how to merge incomplete factor into larger data frame column?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, missing-data

I have not found this problem discussed here.

I often deal with sparse data frames in R (plentiful missing values).  I also need to merge new data into a 'master' df, and that new data is almost always sparse too.

"old school" method seems to be: 1. create a new column of NAs in the master; 2. cross-index the keys between the two data frames. 3. using the index, insert only the new data values from matched keys into the master.

This approach seems to work with numeric and character columns.

```
## master data frame                                                                                                                                                                                              
master = data.frame( id = 1:20, a = rnorm(20) )
master

## what you need to add                                                                                                                                                                                           
new.data = data.frame( id = 2 * 1:10, b = c(rep('a', 5), 
   rep('b', 5) ) )
new.data

## works for character, numeric                                                                                                                                                                    
try1 = master
ind = match( new.data$id, try1$id )
try1$b = NA
try1[ind, 'b'] = new.data$b
try1
str(try1)
```

However, this fails when the new data is a factor: during insertion, factor information is lost and the numeric representation of the factor gets added.

```
## what you need to add is a factor                                                                                                                                                                                         
new.data = data.frame( id = 2 * 1:10, b = factor( c(rep('a', 5), 
     rep('b', 5) ), ordered = TRUE ) )
new.data

## works for character, numeric                                                                                                                                                                                   
## not factors                                                                                                                                                                                                    
try1 = master
ind = match( new.data$id, try1$id )
try1$b = NA
try1[ind, 'b'] = new.data$b
str(try1$b)
```

Of course, one could re-create the factor in the master data frame, but this would be laborious and also prone to errors.  Looking for an elegant, or at least non-ugly, solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left_join` from the `dplyr` package:

```
master %>%
  left_join(new.data, by = "id")
```

Comment: Thanks.  dplyr behaves better than the old-school R methods in its treatment of factors here.  In spite of my initial chagrin/rejection after trying to use dplyr within functions, I'll return to it now.  I think Hadley has improved some of the behavior that was driving me crazy previously.